# C# importing different libraries depending on need

Tags: c#, selenium, import, nunit

I am making a unit test in Selenium using Nunit (in case that matters).

For this unit test i have some libraries containing different language translations of all the options.
Each library has a class named the same thing, with a ton of strings all with the same names, just different strings inside them. 
+
I have a config file where you chose which language you want to run the tests in. Is there a smart way to load the needed language library so i can just use the same variable for the strings?

In JavaScript I could use require(string). And as the input is a string, I could use a variable to change which actual file was used, but name the variable the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having it as class files you can use json as storage for your translated strings

```
 [{
    "Reference": "Hello World",
    "French": "Bonjour le monde",     
    "Japanese": "Harōwārudo"
}]
```

Then you can create a DTO.

```
 public class OptionsTranslation
 {
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public string French { get; set; }       
    public string Japanese { get; set; }
 }
```

And you just deserialize the json into object, and retrieve value

```
 var options = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OptionsTranslation>>(File.ReadAllText(<jsonFilepath>));
 var frenchOption = options.First(x=> x.Reference.Equals("Hello World").French;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does seem like the best solution, the issue is that i have around 5000 different strings for each langauge and i have 9 languages. It seems like a lot of work if Im understanding how this works right.

Comment: If that is the case, what I would suggest is you create an excel file with the following columns[Reference, French...etc]. You can then create a code for extracting translation data from the cs files to populate your excel file. Once your excel file is populated, you can convert it to a datatable using ExcelDataReader, and serialize it to a json file. Imho will be easier maintain and track translations in excel. whenever you need to update to add new translations. you just need serialize it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to look up the corresponding assembly based on the values from your config file, and then new up an instance of your library class.
Something like this:

```
string typeString = "My.Assembly.Namesapce.MyClass, My.Assembly.Namesapce, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84474dc3c6524430";

// Get a reference to the type.
Type theType = Type.GetType(typeString, true, false);

// Create an instance of that type.
MyClass  theInstance = (MyClass)Activator.CreateInstance(theType);
```

In this instance, you would change `typeString` dependant on what language is chosen in your config file

Alternatively, it seems as though Dynamic Dependency Injection would solve your problem quite nicely. The idea being, that you register multiple types that can be injected in your case the language libraries. Then at runtime, you can inject the correct library depending on the conditions you set.

This is a good guide for achieving this in .Net Core:
http://anthonygiretti.com/2019/01/31/implement-dynamic-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-core-2-2-example-with-multitenancy-scenario/